# ElasticSearch: Is possible to return only value for i.e filtered count

Tags: elasticsearch

As in title:
Elasticsearch request:

```
localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_count?filter_path=-_shards
```

response:

```
{
"count": 1390217
}
```

Is possible to get only value when only one key:value pair is returned?